# DirectX texture and per-pixel desktop transparency

Tags: c++, winapi, directx, directx-11

I have a directX11 texture which is of ARGB format. (different pixels has different alpha value, like the one below)
[image]

I need to render that texture on a transparent Window which means the desktop should appear behind the texture.
I am using [SetLayeredWindowAttributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setlayeredwindowattributes) which could make the window transparent but it's boolean, i.e. a pixel appears either fully transparent or doesn't appear. I need to achieve per-pixel transparency level - where darkness is defined by the alpha value of the pixel (Something like AlphaBlend). How to achieve it?

Comment: "how to convert DirectX11 texture to a GDI bitmap?"   According to the Doc: [the DXGI format is not GDI compatible](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct2d/d1131)

Comment: Have you got any updates? If your case has been solved, please help to mark answers. If not, just feel free to contact us. Your understanding and cooperation will be grateful.

Comment: Although the answers and comments here were very helpful, I didn't implement what I was looking for. The topic is a bit advanced for me. I hope this will be helpful to other peers having a similar issue.

Answer (score 1):

Use `UpdateLayeredWindow` instead. Select a 32-bit ARGB bitmap into the source HDC.

A more fancy solution is `WS_EX_NOREDIRECTIONBITMAP` and `ICompositorDesktopInterop` but this is probably overkill in this case unless you need to do updates often. MSDN magazine did have a few [articles](https://kennykerr.ca/2014/09/02/directcomposition/) about this. DirectComposition is intended to interop with Direct2D etc. where as `UpdateLayeredWindow` is much older and predates the DWM and any kind of visual tree rendering.

Comment: I saw some examples using `UpdateLayeredWindow` but how to convert DirectX11 texture to a GDI bitmap?

Comment: There are various ways of creating the bitmap, the fastest is probably dib section and a raw byte buffer if you can get DX to deliver the bytes in the correct format. If you intend to do animations at high FPS then DirectComposition is perhaps a better approach.

Comment: Thanks for informing me about DirectComposition.